# Spring-Aspect - find if method call stack has specific package classes

Tags: java, spring-aspects

I'm very new to Spring-Aspect. In fact, I just need to make a fix, while never implemented with aspect before.
So, I have the following classes (not real names :D):

1. `Validate` in package `com.my` which calls
2. `ValidateService` which calls
3. `DAO`

What I need is an aspect, that will be called only if call to `DAO` methods (say `add`, `create` etc.) has it's deep origin from `Validate` class. Like the following:

`* com.my..*.*(..)` -> `ValidateService.validate()` -> `…` [some other classes may be envolved] `…` -> DAO.add(..)

So I am interested in this part:

`* com.my..*.*(..)` -> [whatever] -> `DAO.add(..)`

Tried `within`, `call`, `execute` but no luck. Can someone help? **Using Spring Aspect 1.7.0**

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I wrote AspectJ pointcuts, but I think you are missing using the `cflow` pointcut descriptor.  It takes one argument, which is itself the pointcut. The pointcut resolves to true when execution is under the control flow (cflow) of the pointcut that is passed in.

So, you want to do something like this:

```
pointcut daoCall() : call(* * DAO.*(..)) &&
  cflow(within(ValidateService.validate()));
```

I may have some of the syntax muddled. So, take a look at the docs on cflow, but above is the basic idea.

Comment: Well, Forgot to mention I'm using Spring Aspectj, wich does not support `cflow`. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's Spring-Aspects, not AspectJ. Two separate languages.

Comment: Oops, shame on me. I said I'm new to it ) I'l fix the description